# Apache restart only for one web page Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, configuration, restart

I have few web pages on my Ubuntu/Apache server. Now I had to change DocumentRoot for one domain. After I changed DocumentRoot in xyz.conf file, requests to domain does not match desired DocumentRoot directory. Apache keeps the old path in the cache. Now I need to restart Apache, but dont know how to do it only for this domain. Can somebody explain me please how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot reload just one config file. However, a `sudo service apache2 restart` usually takes less than 0.2 seconds. Do you need something faster?

Comment: But it should be possible. How commercial hostings do this stuff? It is unreal to restart apache every time somebody wants to change his DocumentRoot. How it is made on production servers?

Comment: It seems `systemctl reload apache2` is what I want. Or `service apache2 reload` on other OS.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Comment: There it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "only this site" in a simple Apache virtual hosting setup, as all sites are defined in one configuration typically built from many files. There is one server process that may spawn additional processes or threads to serve requests but they each just see the whole config.

To put a configuration change into effect you can mostly do a graceful reload, which is what is happening when you do `service reload apache2` or `systemctl reload apache2` or `apache2ctl graceful`. This takes care to finish serving every outstanding request with the old server process and then hand new connections to the new server process that sees the new configuration. There will not be noticeable unavailability. I say "mostly" because there are a couple of configuration changes that do require a full restart.

You asked in comments how production services handle this, if the web server has to be restarted every time there is a configuration change. The answer is that setups which desire high availability would put load balancers in front of web servers so that there were multiple servers available to answer requests. That way a configuration change can be done by rolling reload without clients noticing.

This is done not only for configuration changes; it also helps to protect against problems with any small number of web server hosts. In your current setup you have just this one web server host: if anything happens to it, it all the sites are down.

Very popular web sites will eventually also exceed the ability of a single web server to serve them, so a load balancer is the way to scale horizontally.

The single point of failure then becomes the load balancer, so that too must be made highly available and so it goes on, with ever more complex setups.

Answer (score 0):

Like grifferz said, this isn't really supported by Apache directly. However, a workaround might to be to point Apache at a path to a symlink, which is static, and then update that symlink to point to the changed true document root.

That way, Apache never requires a reload or restart, but you can still change the effective DocumentRoot.